# writing code in function prototype JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Company where i'm working right now they are writing sth like this all the time ...

```
function art() {
};
art.prototype = { sth functions, var's }
```

or

```
function art() {
};
art.prototype = (function () {
 return{
sth functions, vars 
}
})();
```

what is a purpose of this habits, that is changing something?

Comment: Do you know what the prototype is?

Comment: search prototype on google, explanations and tutorials galore. hmm.. and they thought it would be a good idea to add `class` to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototypes are one of the core features of JavaScripts. [Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) *is basically an object from which other objects inherit properties*. Every object has its own prototype property from which it inherits its members (properties, methods).

Take this classical polymorphism example:

```js
// Car Top Class
var Car = function (brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
};

Car.prototype.say = function () {
    return 'I am ' + this.brand;
};

// Models inheriting from car
function Mercedes() {
    this.fourwheels = '4Matic';
};
Mercedes.prototype = new Car('Mercedes-Benz');

function Audi() {
    this.fourwheels = 'Quatro';
};
Audi.prototype = new Car('Audi');

// ---

var mercedes = new Mercedes();
var audi = new Audi();

console.log(`${ mercedes.say() } with ${ mercedes.fourwheels }`);
console.log(`${ audi.say() } with ${ audi.fourwheels }`);
```

..especially see the `Mercedes.prototype = new Car('Mercedes-Benz');` by allocating new instance of `Car` to `Mercedes` prototype we are achieving inheritance (Mercedes will receive the Car's members) which plays the key role to polymorphism in this example.

Comment: Good explanation. Maybe also include a link to the stackoverflow docs? https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/592/inheritance/723/standard-function-prototype#t=201708110825165874623

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you. It seems that no new links to documentation are possible. SO doesn't let me save it and points me here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation

Comment: Aw man. Sad times. I didn't know about this decision. Thanks for considering it anyway.